# Time Series Analysis vs Linear Regression for GDP data?

Tags: regression, time-series, forecasting, macroeconomics

I am trying to build a simple econometrics model that uses urban population, total factor productivity among other things to predict future GDP of a country. First I approached the problem by using linear regression (using Python) on the data, there’s definitely a correlation between urban population & total productivity and the GDP of a country.

Here’s the results of the model (Data for all predictors and the dependent variable is yearly & raw (no diff or log) and it’s for the US):
[image: GLS Results]

What I am planning to do is to use time series analysis (ETS or ARIMA) to forecast the values in the factors, feed that in into the above linear model, then predict future GDP. Is this the right approach, or is vector autoregression more suitable for this? I understand there’s autocorrelation in GDP, but from what I have understood from [this](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/4/8) chapter in the Forecasting book, it seems like it’s not a very wrong approach to use linear regression on time series data.

Comment: Bottom line: Regression, time series, auto regressive, transfer function, ARMA, ARIMA, ARMAX, distributed lag, etc. all these are blah blah that academics invented because they had to supposedly invent something new, however they are all the same thing. You are free to use any independent variable (or its lags), or dependent variable (its lags) on the right side of the equation as long as you check that the residuals are stationary. The standard regression software will not check this as part of its standard tests. The complexity of the models you can build are limited by number of samples.

Comment: While they are of course related, "all the same thing" is vastly exaggerated. ARMAX has external regressors, while ARMA only relates the series to its own lags and MA error terms, for example.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Take a complex model with all the mushrooms, pepperoni, anchovies, zuccini, etc. and zero the coefficients of the terms that you don't like. It is still a Pizza.

Comment: Yes, there may be a common encompassing general approach of which the others are special cases. But that is something else than to say they are all the same. Also, this is just how science progresses, with people from different areas working on similar approaches until it is realized later that they are related.

Comment: @ChristophHanck I would agree with you however still new books are published by academics presenting all these topics as if they are very different tools and the obvious connection is never made, which is just a ego show-off in the expense of the students' struggle with these topics.